# Image color changes when captured and saved from camera opencv

Tags: image, opencv, colors

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoYoT.png) [Captuerd Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHxL4.png) I have to capture and save a depth image from a camera. The depth image is color encoded. Here's what I am doing

```
  Mat outColor = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_32FC3);
  for (int h = 0; h < outGray.rows; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < outGray.cols; w++)
        {
            outColor.at<cv::Vec3f>(h, w)[0] = point[j].x *255;
            outColor.at<cv::Vec3f>(h, w)[1] = point[j].y *255;
            outColor.at<cv::Vec3f>(h, w)[2] = point[j].z *255;

            j++;
        }
  }
  imwrite("E:/softwares/1.8.0.71/bin/depthImageColor.png", outColor);
```

But the color has changed in the saved image. It doesnt look same as wot is shown in the camera interface. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: now I am getting an entirely different color in the image. Am i using the wrong scale factor to multiply the pixel values?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? can you post the original image, output image and expected output ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: They wont look same as you are explicitly changing the pixel color values in  `outColor.at<cv::Vec3f>(h, w)[0] = point[j].x *255;`, What is the problem statement, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want the output image to look same as the original image. If I am not scaling the image, nothing is visible